# How to use variables in the Schedule field of a "Poll SCM" trigger

Tags: jenkins, triggers

I have multiple projects with "Poll SCM" triggers. The Schedule field accepts concrete date/time of format `MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW`.

In case we want to change the polling time, we have to go through all projects, and modify accordingly.

How can I use a build variable, say, `$Poll_time`, in the Schedule field, and the variable will be instantiated at build time?